# Adding items in a list into a new list

Tags: python

```
num = [10,10,6,7,12,12,9,7,7,8]  
for x in range(2):
        num1 = num[0] + num[1]
        for x in range(2):
            num.pop(0)
```

I'm not sure if this is right or wrong but i tried to add numbers from a different lists. Then the sum goes straight to num1 to make a list.

Expected outcome:

```
>>> num1
[20, 13, 24, 16, 15]
```

outcome:

```
>>> num1 = num[0] + num[1]
>>> num1
15
```

Comment: Could you perhaps show a smaller example of what your trying to do? It's difficult for us to scan through all that code to see whats wrong.

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Note: `if len(str(Id)) != 3` => `if 100 <= Id <= 999` :). Also, you would probably need a `test.clear()` inside the **inner** `for` loop.

Comment: I fixed my question hopfully it makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

I looked around a bit for some answers although I don't understand what you want really. I'll just base this from the title...

The list method "pop" will remove an item based on the index and return the item removed. Use this by "pop"ing the first list you have items inside of with the index you need then using the return value to append into the new list. It would look something like this...

```
list_two.append( list_one.pop( list_one.index( item ) ) )
```

From left to right this adds into the second list the value returned from a pop on the first list you are trying to get data from. The data you are getting is based on what the index of the item is.

Hope this helps in some way.